# Is the set $\{5a+2:a\in\mathbb Z\}$ a subset of $\{4b+3:b\in\mathbb Z\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X = \{m \in \mathbb Z | m = 5a + 2 \text{ for some integer } a\}$, $Y \{n \in \mathbb Z | n = 4b + 3 \text{ for some integer } b\}$.  Is $X$ a subset of $Y$?

I feel no,  $X$ is not a subset of $Y$, because $X$ has $12$ as its element for $a=2$.
$Y$ does not have $12$ as its element for all values of b.

Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is correct.  Since $12 \in X$ and $12 \not \in Y$, $X$ is not a subset of $Y$.